# Spring Security login returns 404

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am currently working on my blog in Spring framework. I am implementing the Spring Security for login purpose. Everything works as expected until I submit the login credentials which is always returning 404 code.

**Here is my web.xml cod**e

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>avispring</display-name>          

<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/404.html</location>
</error-page>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-database.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>        
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>        
</servlet-mapping>
```

**Here is my spring security code:**

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/avispring"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
</bean>
<security:debug/>
<security:http auto-config="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_check" access="permitAll"/>
    <security:form-login        
    login-page="/login.html"
    authentication-failure-url="/login?login_error=1"
    default-target-url="/admin/home.html"/>     
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:jdbc-user-service 
            data-source-ref="dataSource"
            users-by-username-query="select USERNAME,PASSWORD,ENABLED from USER_AUTHENTICATION where USERNAME=?"
            authorities-by-username-query="select u1.USERNAME,u2.ROLE from USER_AUTHENTICATION u1,USER_AUTHORIZATION u2 where u1.USER_ID=u2.USER_ID and u1.USERNAME=?"/>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

**part of my login.jsp code is**

```
<form action="<c:url value="/login"/>" method="post">
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="username">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8">
          <div class="checkbox icheck">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox"> Remember Me
            </label>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.col -->
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat"     name="submit">Sign In</button>
        </div><!-- /.col -->
      </div>
    </form>
```

**and the console output is**

*Oct 16, 2015 1:06:03 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/avispring/login] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'*

**Note:**

1. I am using spring 4.2.1 and spring security 4.0.2
2. Most of the forums are pointing to the context path i.e **[appname/login]** or **[appname/j_spring_security_check]** and I think mine is ok regarding it

Please help...

**UPDATE:**

when I used log4j, the debug output at the time of form submission is as follows:

> DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@c8b445
>   DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'spring' processing POST request for [/avispring/login]
>   DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping@16fffcf] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
>   DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /login
>   DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/login]
>   DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping@138f01b] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
>   DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - No handler mapping found for [/login]
>   DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping@1ff154c] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
>   DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - No handler mapping found for [/login]
>   WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/avispring/login] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
>   DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@c8b445
>   DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
>   DEBUG: org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Publishing event in WebApplicationContext for namespace 'spring-servlet': ServletRequestHandledEvent: url=[/avispring/login]; client=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]; method=[POST]; servlet=[spring]; session=[BC0FB7E62DC0AFABD8EF72B8BF1CED54]; user=[null]; time=[3ms]; status=[OK]
>   DEBUG: org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Publishing event in Root WebApplicationContext: ServletRequestHandledEvent: url=[/avispring/login]; client=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]; method=[POST]; servlet=[spring]; session=[BC0FB7E62DC0AFABD8EF72B8BF1CED54]; user=[null]; time=[3ms]; status=[OK]
>   DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@bb82df
>   DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'spring' processing POST request for [/avispring/404.html]
>   DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping@16fffcf] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
>   DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /404.html
>   DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Found 1 matching mapping(s) for [/404.html] : [{[/404.html]}]
>   DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Returning handler method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.avispring.controllers.HelloController.errorPage()]
>   DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Testing handler adapter [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter@511db5]
>   DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Testing handler adapter [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter@1a86ee]
>   DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Testing handler adapter [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter@c26a5f]
>   DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod - Invoking [HelloController.errorPage] method with arguments []
>   DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod - Method [errorPage] returned [ModelAndView: reference to view with name '/404'; model is null]
>   DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name '/404'; URL [/WEB-INF/jsp//404.jsp]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
>   DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView - Rendering view with name '/404' with model {} and static attributes {}
>   DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView - Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/jsp//404.jsp] in InternalResourceView '/404'
>   DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@bb82df
>   DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
>   DEBUG: org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Publishing event in WebApplicationContext for namespace 'spring-servlet': ServletRequestHandledEvent: url=[/avispring/404.html]; client=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]; method=[POST]; servlet=[spring]; session=[BC0FB7E62DC0AFABD8EF72B8BF1CED54]; user=[null]; time=[1ms]; status=[OK]
>   DEBUG: org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Publishing event in Root WebApplicationContext: ServletRequestHandledEvent: url=[/avispring/404.html]; client=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]; method=[POST]; servlet=[spring]; session=[BC0FB7E62DC0AFABD8EF72B8BF1CED54]; user=[null]; time=[1ms]; status=[OK]

Comment: did you try it j_spring_security_check instead of /login?

Comment: ya, I have already tried that. At first I had used **j_spring_security_check** but it did not work so I surfed on internet and found that with later versions it was changed to **/login**

Comment: @We are Borg: that didn't help

Comment: Sorry, forgot to write whole, with context path as '/' and /j_spring_security_check . Meanwhile also turn on org.springframework in debug mode in your logging framework.

Comment: @We are Borg: ya tried both but no progress. Could you clarify on the debug mode you are talking about? I have already enabled debug mode in the sucurity xml file

Comment: Sad to hear that. Check out this pastebin : http://pastebin.com/pJgyZw9r .. So, you can setup Log4j.xml for you application and just set the level value for packages. This way, you will see all debug messages and will be easier to pin-point the underlying issue. Check out the dependencies required for Log4j.xml for your projcet. Also, set auto-config to false

Comment: @We are Borg : Thanks a lot for your help. I have implemented log4j and the debug output at the time of form submission is updated above :)

Comment: This is the security config and web.xml I have and they work fine. Just replace the authentication-manager and stuff in web.xml which you find extremely important. Psatebin link : http://pastebin.com/PEm5WTif

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok that was so frustrating and I have found my answer by hit and trial. To all others who are facing my problem I am posting my solution. I had to change only one line in my web.xml file. I had to replace this code

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

with this code

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

and I don't even need this line in spring-security.xml file

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_check" access="permitAll"/>
```

Hope that might help somebody. Happy coding...

Answer (score 3):

Did you try setting the `login-processing-url` attribute of your `<security:form-login>` element? I use the same up-to-date versions of Spring and Spring Security as you and I added the `login-processing-url` attribute as follows:

```
login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
```

Everything works properly, and I don't even need the following element:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_check" access="permitAll"/>
```

Of course, if you wish to use `/login` instead of `/j_spring_security_check`, you are free to do so. Just make sure the URIs you put in your JSP and in your Spring Security configuration file match.

Hope this will help...

Jeff

------------ UPDATE ------------

I think about it... Spring Security introduced Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) protection in version 4. When I updated my code, in order to avoid adding CSRF management in all my protected JSPs (not necessary for my business needs), I had to add the following element in my `<security:http>` element:

```
<security:csrf disabled="true"/>
```

Please give it a try and tell me whether it worked.

Comment: yes, I did set **login-processing-url** before but it didn't work. I also tried setting  **username-parameter** and **password-parameter** as well but no luck :(

Comment: Sorry about that... I will definitely need to see the rest of your code to find out what the differences are between your code and mine around credentials handling.

Comment: now I have only the controller code left should I include that one too?

Comment: I don't think it is likely to have anything to do with your problem, but if you add it I will have a look at it. I really double-checked my configuration and according to your previous notes, it should be quite isomorphous to mine by now.

Comment: did you get any solutions? I'm really stuck in this. :(

Comment: I'll try to have a look at another project in which I configured Spring Security, hopefully version 4, this weekend. I will tell you the outcome of my investigations tomorrow or Monday.

Comment: @ Jeff Morin: Thank you so much for your help but I have already found my solution. see below :)

Comment: What was the solution @AbhisekLamsal ? I'm having the same issue

Comment: @RonSher look  at the springSecurityFilterChain url pattern in the accepted answer. I have stated it above. If it still doesn't work please tell me