# Error 403 vs Error 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I wanted to make sure only admins get into the /settings page.

The problem is that when a normal members access it, it shows error 404.

Shouldn't it be error 403?? The page exists but a member doesn't have authorization to enter it.

What's wrong??

```
  @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/settings").hasAuthority("Administrator")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin().permitAll()
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard")
                .failureUrl("/login?error")
                .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
            .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler)
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/errors/error403")
            .and()
                .csrf().disable();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure ""/errors/error403" exists ? It could lead to a 404 if the 403 page doesn't exist. Giving a `/settings > <Access restrict> --> 403 page --> <Page not found> --> 404 page` kind of redrect.

Comment: Yes it exists. I put a debug on the error pages controller and it enters the error404 method when I access the page with a member

Comment: have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33166139/spring-security-login-returns-404? or  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42797419/spring-security-404-page-for-unauthenticated-users

Comment: If you've got a breakpoint on the error pages controller then can't you see the condition that's sending it to the 404?

Comment: @user9729328 Enter the URL `http://localhost:<PORT>/errors/error403` of your access denied page in your browser. Do you see the page or do you get 404?